# How to mock a call-by-name argument (like getOrElse) using ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, mocking, callbyname

I'd like to be able to mock a return value of `getOrElse` method so that it returns what is passed as `orElse` call-by-name argument with ScalaMock

```
trait ToBeMocked {
  def getOrElse(arg: Int)(orElse: => String): String
}
```

ScalaMock has to be used because of currying. Running this:

```
class CallByNameMockSpec extends Specification with MockFactory {

  trait ToBeMocked {
    def getOrElse(arg: Int)(orElse: => String): String
  }

  "Mocking functions with call-by-name arguments" should {
    "work" in {
      val m = mock[ToBeMocked]

      (m.getOrElse (_: Int)(_: String)).expects(101, *).onCall((x, y) => y)

      m.getOrElse(101)("result") must beEqualTo("result")
    }
  }

}
```

throws an exception:

```
[error]     ClassCastException:        
test.service.CallByNameMockSpec$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4 cannot be cast to java.lang.String (CallByNameMockSpec.scala:16)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use `Product` version of `onCall` method, convert the second argument to `() => String` and call it:

```
class CallByNameMockSpec extends Specification with MockFactory {

  trait ToBeMocked {
    def getOrElse(arg: Int)(orElse: => String): String
  }

  "Mocking functions with call-by-name arguments" should {
    "work" in {
      val m = mock[ToBeMocked]

      (m.getOrElse (_: Int)(_: String)).expects(101, *).onCall(_.productElement(1).asInstanceOf[() => String]())

      m.getOrElse(101)("result") must beEqualTo("result")
    }
  }

}
```