# How to mock DefaultSyncCacheApi in Play2 Scala Framework v2.6.3 scala v2.12?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework, mockito

I'm writing a unit test for a class that has the Play2 class `DefaultSyncCacheApi` as a dependency.
I'm calling the method `getOrElseUpdate[A: ClassTag](key: String, expiration: Duration)(orElse: => A): A` from inside the class that I'm testing.

Of course, I don't want to test the caching class but I just want to mock it so I can test other functionality.

I tried using Mockito:

```
mockCache = mock[DefaultSyncCacheApi]    
when(mockCache.getOrElseUpdate(any(),any())(any())(any()).thenReturn(Future[String])
```

I started with any() in the first place, then I also tried:

```
  when(mockCache.getOrElseUpdate[List[Item]](any(),any())
  (any[List[Item]])
  (any[ClassTag[List[Item]]])
  ).thenReturn(List(new Item))
```

I always get the same error:

```
InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
```

So, in the end I'm not able to apply all 4 matchers from the method definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking a function with pass-by-name arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948519/mocking-a-function-with-pass-by-name-arguments)

Comment: So should I use Scala Mock instead? In the end I created a TestClass implementation for the cache class but is like a workaround.

Comment: Yes, you can go with ScalaMock, but even there the syntax [for describing call-by-name is terrible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298495/5794617). But if you're mocking not so many classes/traits which contain methods with call-by-name, you can go with your own mocks (fake implementations).

Comment: Yes, that looks nasty. I'll go with fake implementation for now. Thanks.